# Contents Overlapping the fixed header menu in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I have a website in which I want to have a fixed menu ... But the problem is that fixed menu is working properly on home page but it is not overlapping with contents on other pages...

I tried by adding margin-top: 72px in the content CSS but nothing works for me..
Can anyone please help me with this... please

Home Page: http://trueconf.in

Any other pages like : http://trueconf.in/download

Comment: fix your code https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ftrueconf.in%2F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be in all the pages of your website. Looks like some of the element's property is overriding your header's z-index. Increasing your z-index value for the header should fix it.
Increase your z-index value from 5 to 10000 in the css property`.default-sec` class in your main.css file.

main.css

```
   .default-sec{
    z-index : 10000;
    }
```

Comment: can you please have a look at the homepage menu trueconf.in the main menu is transparent I tried to increase the opacity but custom CSS doesn't seems to be working... Can you tell me where should I actually put that

Comment: Sorry but there is a problem.... Main menu is fixed now by increasing z-index value but the contact us pop-up form is now not coming over it..what should i do now for that..

Comment: @Vishal Chouhan, looks like the contact form is working fine and am not sure what problem are you referring to. Can you brief me as to how and where you want the contact form to be placed?

Answer (score 1):

```
#header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Something else on the page has a high z-index value and is messing your display. When you add that z-index value to your header it works on the download page.

Answer (score 0):

When backend logged in

```
if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) {
          echo '<style>.home-header{top: 32px;}</style>';
        }
```